# Python lamda function to sort list of tuples based on relationship to previous tuple

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

Is it possible to use `sorted(list, lambda x:..)` to sort a list of tuples such that the first value of the next tuple equals the second value of the previous tuple?

```
list_of_tuples = [("JFK", "DEN"), ("LAX", "ORD"), ("DEN", "SFO"), ("LAS", "LAX"), ("ORD", "ATL"), ("ATL", "JFK"), ("SFO", "LAS")]
Desired_output = [('JFK', 'DEN'), ('DEN', 'SFO'), ('SFO', 'LAS'), ('LAS', 'LAX'), ('LAX', 'ORD'), ('ORD', 'ATL'), ('ATL', 'JFK')]
```

I know how to sort by either value in the tuple (`sorted(list_of_tuples, key = lambda x: x[0])`), but what is the best way to sort using lambda and somehow reference the previous value in the list?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with `sorted()`. But you can solve it using for loop.

```
d = dict(list_of_tuples)
res = [list_of_tuples[0]]
prev = res[0]

for idx in range(len(list_of_tuples) - 1):
    prev = (prev[1], d[prev[1]])
    res.append(prev)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[('JFK', 'DEN'), ('DEN', 'SFO'), ('SFO', 'LAS'), ('LAS', 'LAX'), ('LAX', 'ORD'), ('ORD', 'ATL'), ('ATL', 'JFK')]
```

Comment: `list_of_tuples = ((1, 2), (3, 1))` `Traceback (most recent call last): KeyError: 2`

Comment: see the input in the post 2nd value of every tuple is first element in another tuple

Comment: Looks [possible](https://repl.it/repls/ImperfectTriflingComputer#main.py) to me...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `sorted()`. What you are looking for is a **eulerian path** in a graph.

Here the vertices of the graph are your tuples, and there is a directed edge from one tuple to another if the last value of the one matches the first value of the other.

### Simple solution with a `dict`

However, if there is always only one possible candidate for the next tuple, and you know that you can start with the first element in the list, then the problem is much simpler and you don't need any complex eulerian-path algorithm.

First, put the elements of the list in an efficient data structures that allows searching for the next tuple easily. You can use a python dict. Then, add the elements one by one.

```py
list_of_tuples = [("JFK", "DEN"), ("LAX", "ORD"), ("DEN", "SFO"), ("LAS", "LAX"), ("ORD", "ATL"), ("ATL", "JFK"), ("SFO", "LAS")]

dict_first = {}
for pair in list_of_tuples:
  dict_first[pair[0]] = pair

result = [list_of_tuples[0]]
key = list_of_tuples[0][-1]
result = []
while key in dict_first and len(result) < len(list_of_tuples):
  result.append(dict_first[key])
  key = result[-1][-1]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('JFK', 'DEN'), ('DEN', 'SFO'), ('SFO', 'LAS'), ('LAS', 'LAX'), ('LAX', 'ORD'), ('ORD', 'ATL'), ('ATL', 'JFK')]
```

### Using networkx.eulerian_path

In the general case where you really do need an algorithm for the eulerian path problem, there is one in module networkx:

- [networkx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_path](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_path.html)

```py
from networkx import Graph, eulerian_path

list_of_tuples = [("JFK", "DEN"), ("LAX", "ORD"), ("DEN", "SFO"), ("LAS", "LAX"), ("ORD", "ATL"), ("ATL", "JFK"), ("SFO", "LAS")]

G = Graph()
G.add_edges_from(list_of_tuples)
result = list(eulerian_path(G))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('JFK', 'DEN'), ('DEN', 'SFO'), ('SFO', 'LAS'), ('LAS', 'LAX'), ('LAX', 'ORD'), ('ORD', 'ATL'), ('ATL', 'JFK')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
list_of_tuples = [("JFK", "DEN"), ("LAX", "ORD"), ("DEN", "SFO"),
                  ("LAS", "LAX"), ("ORD", "ATL"), ("ATL", "JFK"),
                  ("SFO", "LAS")]
Desired_output=[list_of_tuples[0]]
for i in range (len(list_of_tuples)):
    for j in  list_of_tuples:
        if Desired_output[i][1]==j[0]:
            Desired_output.append(j)
print(Desired_output)
```